# Using jQuery to add Event Handler doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate a table of data and after I've made a row, attach an event handler to it. I've started by making a small test:

```
function AddActivityAbstractOnClickEvent(element) {
    $(element).on('click', GetActivityFullDescription(1));
}

function GetActivityFullDescription(id) {
    alert("Click");
}
```

And I call it here:

```
function GetActivityAbstracts() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:52535/ExampleService.svc/GetTestTableData", function (testData) {
        var object = $.parseJSON(testData);
        var activityTable = $('#activityTable');
        $.each(object, function (index, value) {
            //index here is used to generate unique ids
            var activityId = this['ActivityId'];
            var activityName = this['ActivityName'];
            var activityResponsible = this['Responsible'];
            var activityEstimatedSavings = parseFloat(this['EstimatedSavings']).toFixed(2);
            var activityEstimatedStart = this['EstimatedStart'];
            var activityEstimatedEnd = this['EstimatedEnd'];
            var activityStatus = this['Status'];
            // TODO: Make more user-friendly Status Descriptions instead of C# enum values.
            var tableElement =
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td id = "activityId_' + index + '" style = "vertical-align: middle; align: center;">'
                    + activityId + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">' +
                    '<div class="status-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"' +
                    'title=" ' + activityStatus + '" style="background-color:' +
                    GetColumnColor(activityStatus) + ';"></div></td>' +
                    '<td id = "activityName_' + index + '" style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityName + '</td>' +
                    //Add index for ids here
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityResponsible + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedSavings + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedStart + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedEnd + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            var $tableElement = $(tableElement);
            activityTable.append($tableElement);
            AddActivityAbstractOnClickEvent($tableElement);
        });
        $('#current-data-table').append(activityTable);

        /* This call is necessary because the table is added dynamically */
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"').tooltip();
    });
}
```

When I go to my website however, the "Click" alert appears with every row that I add to the table before I add the table data itself but nothing happens when I click any of the rows on the site.

Comment: Change `$(element).on('click', GetActivityFullDescription(), false);` ==> `$(element).on('click', GetActivityFullDescription);`

Comment: 1) Your `click()` handler syntax is wrong. 2) Use a delegated syntax handler so that you don't need to bind the event on every row.

Comment: @Tushar that didn't work. It fixed the first problem, but nothing happens when I click.

Comment: It would be nice to know why I got a -1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Since you can see where I am at fault, would you be able to provide a possible solution? :) I'm still fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full correction and commented code.

```
function GetActivityAbstracts() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:52535/ExampleService.svc/GetTestTableData", function (testData) {
        var object = $.parseJSON(testData);
        var activityTable = $('#activityTable');

        // create HTML only by using $.map, it's better for perfs to generate all HTML before adding it into the dom
        var html = $.map(object, function (item, index) {
            //index here is used to generate unique ids
            var activityId = item['ActivityId'];
            var activityName = item['ActivityName'];
            var activityResponsible = item['Responsible'];
            var activityEstimatedSavings = parseFloat(item['EstimatedSavings']).toFixed(2);
            var activityEstimatedStart = item['EstimatedStart'];
            var activityEstimatedEnd = item['EstimatedEnd'];
            var activityStatus = item['Status'];
            // TODO: Make more user-friendly Status Descriptions instead of C# enum values.
            // move id  attr on on <tr> 
            return '<tr id="activityId_' + index + '">' +
                    '<td  style = "vertical-align: middle; align: center;">'
                    + activityId + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">' +
                    '<div class="status-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"' +
                    'title=" ' + activityStatus + '" style="background-color:' +
                    GetColumnColor(activityStatus) + ';"></div></td>' +
                    '<td id = "activityName_' + index + '" style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityName + '</td>' +
                        //Add index for ids here
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityResponsible + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedSavings + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedStart + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedEnd + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';

        });
        // Add HTML into activityTable
        activityTable.html(html);
        // add event by using delegate event.
        activityTable.on('click', 'tr', function() {
            GetActivityFullDescription($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        $('#current-data-table').append(activityTable);

        /* This call is necessary because the table is added dynamically */
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
}
```

Comment: update your first code and give us the content of `AddActovotyAbstractOnClickEvent` please

Comment: I have updated my answer with your full code and some improvements

Comment: Thank you!! What was the issue??

Comment: I don't know because the corrected code you posted was correct, but you added 1 click event on each row, and generated 1 <tr> element each time. 
I just move click event and rows generations in only one step.